# php dom document loadHTML and getElementByTagName returns nothing

Tags: php

```
$urlToScrap = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiZmxpcGJvYXJkLmFwcCJd";
$pageContentData = file_get_contents($urlToScrap);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($pageContentData);
$listOfDivs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach ($listOfDivs as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute("class") == "doc-banner-icon"){
        $img = $div->getElementsByTagName("img");
        var_dump($img->getAttribute("src"));
    }
}
```

returns empty.

I have the following elements in the dom:

```
<div class="doc-banner-icon"><img src="somesrc"></div>
```

I'm trying to get the img src and since in the page there are many images, I would like to first get the parent div and then extract the image inside it.

The solution is here:

```
$urlToScrap = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flipboard.app#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiZmxpcGJvYXJkLmFwcCJd";
$pageContentData = file_get_contents($urlToScrap);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($pageContentData);
$listOfDivs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach ($listOfDivs as $div) {
    if($div->getAttribute("class") == "doc-banner-icon"){
        $listOfImages = $div->getElementsByTagName("img");
        foreach($listOfImages as $img){
            var_dump($img->getAttribute("src"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$listOfImages = $doc->find("img");` ?

Comment: @DevlshOne, dom document doesn't have a find function

Comment: Aw, sorry, been working with the `simple_html_dom` plugin too much. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't missing anything, `var_dump` doesn't work as you expect on a `DOMNodeList`.  Try this instead:

```
$listOfImages = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach ($listOfImages as $img) {
    $imgClass = $img->getAttribute('class');

    echo $imgClass;
}
```

In your updated question, just change:

```
$img->getAttribute("src")
```

to:

```
$img->item(0)->getAttribute("src")
```

Given that your selection criteria is fairly complex, you might consider using XPath instead of navigating manually:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($pageContentData);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$img = $xpath->query("//div[@class = 'doc-banner-icon']/img");

var_dump($img->item(0)->getAttribute('src'));
```

Comment: works as a champ, thanks! is there away to look for a class element ?

Comment: If I have a class with a class name and I would like to find it and then get the Img tag inside it, how do I do it ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you update your question with what you are trying to do?

Comment: I can you getAttribute to get an attribute, but how do you get the inner Text of a div ? like you do with jQuery("#id").text() ?